# How can I transform SYSDATE to look like this: 2020-09-02-00.00.00 ? ORACLE

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date

How can I transform SYSDATE to look like this: 2020-09-02-00.00.00 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as timestamp),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MI:SS') from dual
```

Comment: Why do you cast to `TIMESTAMP`? If you insist to get a TIMESTAMP value, then use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` or `SYSTIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

Comment: You probably want `HH24` rather tha `HH` (which defaults to `HH12`).